# oracle 11g, multiple datafiles, does deleting data which may be in an older datfile frees up space?

Tags: oracle11g

I am running Oracle 11g R2 on Oracle Linux 5. It's a large database with around 5 million records added everyday. There are already 5 datafiles, 32G each.

My question is, if I delete old records which may be in the first datafile, would that freed up space in datafile-1 be reused when the latest datafile-5 is full?

Comment: It's maybe a bit more complicated than that; are you inserting new data into the same table you deleted from? (Also [see the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/physical.htm#CNCPT403)). You generally don't need to worry about which datafile(s) your records are in. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, it's the same table that I am inserting data into. The problem is disk usage. I need to add a datafile every 20 days or so.

Comment: And you're deleting the same volume of data - the overall size has stabilised (in terms of number of rows and actual storage you think should be required) but you're still having to add space? How are you deleting the old data, and inserting the new - direct path inserts above the high water mark, perhaps? Have you considered [partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/schemaob.htm#CNCPT1136) to make dropping chunks of old data easier?

Comment: It is already partitioned, I am deleting partition-wise. I just started deleting. Just want to be sure whether that would help.

Comment: @AlexPoole, hello. It's me again. I have deleted 15 days data, therefore datafile-5 should have stopped growing for 15 or so days since data insertion volume for each day is roughly same. But the datafile keeps growing.

Comment: Better late than never, thanks @Alex Poole. Direct path insert was the reason. I had to shrink to overcome.

Comment: If the 5 million records are being added in a daily batch and the direct-path is for performance reasons, you might want to consider inserting into a staging table and then doing a partition exchange into the real table. If the partitioning matches the batch load, that is. [Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-2AF83B38-5895-495F-B3E5-6529A2660AE8.htm#VLDBG1361).